# How to cache history.back like Safari in other browsers?

Tags: browser-cache

I want

> history.back()

to be cached like Safari naturally does.

But this does not happen in other browsers

How can I implement safari like cache of history.back() in other browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can cache the page resources in 'localStorage', but most modern browsers already do something similar(and better). Despite this native browser cache, the code generated from these resources takes a while to be calculated and applied.
You can give a little help to the browser structuring your website pages this way:

```
<script>
    if(!localStorage[location.pathname]) {
        //load this page from server
        localStorage[location.pathname] = getGeneratedPage();
    } else {
        body.innerHTML = parseGeneratedPage(localStorage[location.pathname]);
    }    
</script>
```

This is just a VERY generic example. The getGeneratedPage could be a function which stores ONLY:

- The DOM tree after page load
- CSS rules matched for this page
- JS functions which have at least one listener
- Base64 Images(only recommended for small images or previews of big images)
- etc

Also, you can make a server-side version of this or something like [Opera Turbo](http://www.opera.com/browser/turbo/).
Well, there are countless ways to make your page load in the blink of an eye. Hope it helps.

Comment: Is this can be applied even though page has been appended dynamically through jQuery(JavaScript)?

Comment: Even better. If you are already using XHR(AJAX) in your pages you could just store the responses in localStorage and put all your website pages in a single file but with a lot of XHR requests. Like the Google Search. On Google Search's page ou can search diferent queries through Web, Images, Videos, etc and still in the same location and you can use browser actions to go Back/Forward these 'pages'. Note the only thing changing is the URI Fragment(#), to handle what should be requested.

Comment: so is this somewhat like location.hash? can you explain me with working detail example code?

Comment: Also what about not supporting HTML5 browsers like IE 8?

Comment: I just decided to use <a href="_target"> to resolve my case.
However you inspired me with a considerable solution and I will apply this later on other parts thanks :)